# Repeating syntax above rather than below

Tags: php

Im sure someone has already asked the question in the proper wording but im relatively new to PHP in fact im very new, im trying to get this code to post above, rather than below, currently it posts below. I can't find any helpful information on this.

```
<?php


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Free");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<font color="blue"><br>';
echo ' <font color="grey">';
echo 'by';
echo '<font color="green"> ';
    echo $row['Name'];
      echo '<font color="grey"> cantact me at<font color="yellow"> ';
echo $row['Contact'];

echo '<br>';
echo '<font color="black">';
echo $row['Message'];
    echo '<font color="Yellow">';
    echo $row['Date'];;
    echo '<br><br></font>';


}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Off topic comment, If I were not mistaken, from what I've heard on some people in SO, using `*` in SELECT statement is very very bad, it would be wise if you use the column names itself.

Comment: What do you mean "post"? And "below"? Below what?

Comment: Also you shouldn't use the font tag, it's deprecated in HTML5

Comment: I want that script to repeat above, rather than below. It pulls information submitted from a form and the posts. Every post after that is posted below it, i want it to post above every post

Comment: The `<font>` element was superseded by CSS in 1996. Stop using it.

Comment: @Lauer — http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: I use CSS this is just a test script before I add final touches. I want to make sure it functions properly

Comment: I'm having a hard time to understand what you want. Any html code or anything that you're trying to do?

Comment: I want the posts submitted posted as most recent on top of page that's that final outcome. CUrrently, most recent posts are posted below the last

Comment: try adding after Free on your query, `ORDER BY Date DESC`

Comment: Ill give that a try, but the way I have the date entered into MySQL currently isnt propper. But Ill try

Comment: Do you have any id(primary/unique) on that table, well obviously it should have. Try `GROUP BY whatever_column_name_id ORDER BY Date DESC`

Comment: Yea you nailed it man. Thanks for the help